# How to get updates exporting select

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

Im using dbeaver. How to export updates by using select? I can export inserts, but no updates. Maybe there's other way to do it? Maybe write in select with concat?

Tried to use UPDATE OR, but format doesnt makes me happy....

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl1Ux.png)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean be "export updates using select"? I figure export inserts means take a result set and export a sequence of insert statements which yield that result. But can't really conceptualize what it'd mean to export an update. Could you put your desired result, what you'd get in a perfect world, of the export in the question body?

Comment: Sorry for my english. Yes. When i write select * from table;, i press right click, then press export from query and then i can select how i want to export. I can export like csv, or txt, but also i can export table like inserts, those records.

Comment: For example 

select * from table where .. = 1;
i get 5 rows, when i do export like sql and i select INSERT, dbeaver exports like this:

INSERT INTO (.....) VALUES (....);
INSERT INTO (.....) VALUES (....);
INSERT INTO (.....) VALUES (....);
INSERT INTO (.....) VALUES (....);
INSERT INTO (.....) VALUES (....);

Comment: I also added one more picture which i can choose

Comment: Which format are you expecting? (or: Which one makes you happy)   Please use [edit] to add that info to your question!

Comment: @notgoodprogrammer No worries on the English, I can follow what you are saying informally. Just on a technical level it's not clear. Exporting an insert makes total sense, because an insert doesn't really need context of the target table. An update needs more context though, you are updating data that already exists usually based on some condition or key. So after this export you'd get a text file, right? What do you want the content of that text file to be (please put it as text in the question)?

Comment: Im gonna update or delete those rows from different tables, so its kinda for the backup

Comment: @Luuk i want get format like UPDATE (ALL COLUMNS) VALUES (ALL VALUES) if value is null then null.

Comment: This does not look like the syntax PostgreSQL uses for an [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html), so it will not be possible to do that using a _standard_ tool like [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)

Comment: ohh sorry...

UPDATE table SET column1 = text, column2 = text WHERE id = ;

Comment: not possible using DBEAVER, and I do not know any other tool that does do this.